# RAD Studio XE5 JSON support

Tags: json, c++builder, c++builder-xe5, rad-studio

I am using RAD Studio XE5 for my software development. With the latest version of RAD Studio (10.3), there is a JSON library available in the RTL/VCL for parsing and creating JSON objects.

My question is, is there any similar library which I can use in RAD Studio XE5 (C++) for JSON parsing and object creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RTL in XE5 has the same JSON library that is in 10.3 Rio (and has been in the RTL since RAD Studio 2010).  It is simply located in a different unit.

In XE5, it is in the [`Data.DBXJSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DBXJSON) unit (which was just [`DBXJSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/DBXJSON) prior to the introduction of Unit Scope Names in XE2).

It was moved to the new [`System.JSON`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON) unit in XE6.